# Как сделать сравнение строк в двух файлов на python?

Tags: python

Есть 2 файла. Из первого берется рандомная строчка. Нужно сделать так, что бы он после выбора строки сравнил есть ли она во 2 файле если есть, выбрать заново, а если нет, то идти дальше. Помогите пожалуйста реализовать код.

```
    import random


prof = (random.choice(list(open('C:/Users/denga/Desktop/бункер/Proff.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8"))))
f2 = open("C:/Users/denga/Desktop/бункер/vibor.txt", 'w')
f2.write(prof)

"Тут должно быть сравнение"

my_file = open("rez.txt", 'w')
my_file.write(prof)
my_file.close()
```

Comment: Дайте вопросу заголовок, отражающий суть вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Приблизительно так

```py
def do_something(value):
    # условно пусть будет
    my_file = open("rez.txt", 'a', encoding='utf-8')
    my_file.write(value.rstrip('\n'))
    my_file.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with open('values_to_compare.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as values_to_compare:
        values = values_to_compare.readlines()
    with open('values_list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as values_list:
        list_values = values_list.readlines()

    for v in values:
        if v in list_values:
            do_something(v)
```

Но то, что выше написал, это сравнение строк (содержимого файлов) но не файлов. Про сравнение файлов ниже:

```py
import hashlib

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_1 = open('stock_manager/manage.py', 'rb')
    file_2 = open('test.py', 'rb')
    hash_1 = hashlib.md5(file_1.read())
    hash_2 = hashlib.md5(file_2.read())
    file_1.close()
    file_2.close()
    print(hash_1.hexdigest() == hash_2.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но что-то не так Он просто выводит данные из 2го файла в файл rez.

Comment: @ДенисГаврин Ну как бы это так было задумано, поскольку смысл конечного результата скрыт от меня за семью печатями. Если поделитесь задуманным можно будет попробовать помочь

Comment: Суть такая. Запускается программа и вводится количество игроков. Запускается цикл. Допустим 5 раза. Нужно что бы он брал из файла допустим возраст и записывал его в rez. Программа берет рандомную строчку. И при этом в файле rez строчки не должны повторятся.

Comment: import random
from threading import Thread
    
def main():
    prof = (random.choice(list(open('C:/Users/denga/Desktop/бункер/Proff.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8"))))
    my_file = open("rez.txt", 'w')
    my_file.write(prof)
    my_file.close()

def create_thread(amount):
    for t in range(amount):
        t = Thread(target=main)
        t.start()

if __name__ in '__main__':
    create_thread(amount=int(input('Введите количество игроков: ')))

Comment: В голову пришел способ. Записывать возраст в другой файл и при 2 круге он должен сравнить и если совпало, то перевыбрать.

Comment: @ДенисГаврин, если честно, то пока пытаюсь уловить суть, но по дороге возникают вопросы. к примеру. Вот здесь вот `my_file = open("rez.txt", 'w')` Каждая запись в файл, будет стирать предыдущую причем не важно из какого из (к примеру) пяти потоков она будет производиться. И в оконцовке останется один файл с одной, последней, запсью

Comment: @ДенисГаврин, Во вторых, для того, чтобы поток завершил работу, в каком-то месте должен быть вызван метод join()

Comment: На счет w согласен. Этот код я прост накидал. Пока думаю как реализовать.